# What is the meaning of $1.05 as seen at March For Our Lives?

Tags: united-states, guns, protests

[image: Emma Gonzalez at March for our Lives]

At the March for our Lives rally, the podium has a sticker - **$1.05**. It seems unusual to me, a non-American. What is its meaning?

Comment: I'll have to downvote this question for lack of preliminary research, as it's quite easy to find the answer to this with a search engine.

Comment: @Revetahw Yeah, that's fair. But at the time I had no idea it was NRA or Rubio related, or even a recent development. All I could think of was the song Freedom isn't Free ([$1.05](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%241.05)) which seems related but ... it's not.

Comment: I just searched for "1.05 march for our lives". Google even suggested it as I typed 1.05 ma... Interesting question though.

Comment: @Revetahw And Stack Exchange is supposed to be one of the first sites you find with that search engine.

Comment: @JesseTG Thank you. I agree, Stack Exchange should be the top search result for 50% of searches. A search for "march for our lives $1.05 meaning" returns this page as the top 3 results.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As [Vox explains](https://www.vox.com/2018/3/25/17161118/marjory-stoneman-douglas-students-price-tag-rubio) it is directed at Senator Rubio, who has opposed the March and their movement, representing the value they believe he has placed on their lives by dividing the number of dollars he has received from the NRA by the number of school children purportedly harmed by his pro-gun stance:

> [T]hey came up with it by dividing the amount the National Rifle
>   Association has spent to support Rubio’s campaigns, $3.3 million, by
>   the 3.1 million public and private students in the state. Since
>   Rubio’s first senate bid in 2010, the NRA has spent about $1 million
>   to support his campaigns, and $2.3 million to attack his opponents,
>   according to the Center for Responsive Politics.

Comment: Comments deleted. The question is asking for the message behind this symbol. This is not the place to discuss the merit of that message.

Comment: Do you mean "the number of school children in the state" (which is what the quote says) rather than "purportedly harmed"?

Comment: @JBentley "potentially harmed" might be a better word choice.

Comment: It might be worth noting that one of the speakers explained the tags; the explanation was very similar to the one here, but maybe a direct quote from the speakers themselves would be better?

Answer (score 41):

[The printable PDF on marchforourlives.com](https://marchforourlives.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1dollar5cents_download.pdf) explains the meaning behind this symbol:

> There are 3,140,167* students enrolled in Florida. Marco Rubio has received $3,303,355** from the NRA. That comes out to $1.05 per student.
>
> ON MARCH 24TH WEAR THIS PRICE TAG TO PROTEST POLITICIANS WHO ACCEPT NRA BLOOD MONEY AND DEMAND THEY PASS MEANINGFUL GUN CONTROL LEGISLATION NOW.
>
> *Total number of students enrolled in both public and private Florida schools
>
> **https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/10/04/opinion/thoughts-prayers-nra-funding-senators.html

Comment: Comments deleted. The question is asking for the message behind this symbol. This is not the place to discuss the merit of that message.

Comment: Ah.  Yes, if it does provide the prime source for the reasoning, it's a good answer.

Answer (score 12):

These price tags are meant as a symbol for money that the gun lobby gives to politicians, [according to CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/24/us/march-for-our-lives-price-tags-trnd/index.html):

> Stoneman Douglas freshman Lauren Hogg put it this way as she showed off the tag at the rally in Washington:
>
> “We took the amount of money that [Senator] Marco Rubio took from the NRA, and we divided it by every single student in the state of Florida,” she said. “So, this is how much we’re worth to the Florida government. It’s our price tag.”

The number is disputed, as the CNN article goes on to explain.

Comment: @grovkin: All answers were posted within three minutes of each other, and (I assume) written independently. They also each refer to a different source.